# Issue with variable values in selenium grid execution

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-grid

We are using selenium grid to all UI testcases.

We are facing issue when any variable having value 1 which is getting entered into any text field.

e.g.

set test variable    ${data}    1
input text          ${data}

if a variable has value set to 1 but below value is getting set:

/tmp/21fe989d-6c5d-413b-8365-cf6da42e92b9/upload957182740231871694file/1

Due to this testcases are failing as text field expectes int but it gets above value.

I am not sure from where "/tmp/21fe989d-6c5d-413b-8365-cf6da42e92b9/upload957182740231871694file/" this part is getting appended to the variable value.

This is strage as it happens only when value is 1.

Below is the detail log from test exection:

> 

16:56:00.882    INFO    Typing text '1' into text field 'xpath=//input[@name='floorValue']'

16:56:00.883    DEBUG   POST http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub/session/e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e/elements {"using": "xpath", "sessionId": "e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e", "value": "//input[@name='floorValue']"} 
16:56:00.905    DEBUG   Finished Request

16:56:00.905    DEBUG   POST http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub/session/e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e/element/26/clear {"sessionId": "e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e", "id": "26"}

16:56:00.931    DEBUG   Finished Request
16:56:00.933    DEBUG   POST http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub/session/e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e/file {"sessionId": "e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e", "id": "26", "file": "UEsDBBQAAAAIAGJU9Uhr90YTkgoAAF5CAAABAAAAMe1bbW/bOBL+HP8Kwf5g+dZRGvd6iwtOi3Ob\n9tBDui2SvuCQBAQtMTa7suQVqdTeX398lUhJfpHk7uWA+kMiUjMPh8OZ4QwlDR7SZOkEyXKZxCCj\nOMIUI+JdYUIvIYUOXq6SlDq63asnX6BohVJNnCIY0iTEAZXkaTJLqBfhWQpTTv0ywxF9G2ty1ezl\n3PqK0BTH87wfxmGy1C2KlzldQnKOTX4ZQooEkRBBt5yD747FECGK9KTlLOAKa6oomc9RKm/eoAjF\nOFtOrsQsN5qm3F9P/XpNUUxwEpNtfAVFj/0GDvHLFO6oNyBoUukvODmFk6WR4zv9BaWri7Oz858n\n3vnfvL96538/v5hMJmfT8F8Qx+/mS3r25fH36NNiEX96DOM/vK9k1edDBxEkxHnFlpiiD2kSZgF1\nRxe93kmIHhwAcIwpAC5B0QPrPTkZkIwZhvuSL947GEOmsLG46eW0I0ZG0w2nPhlYwIxmBgkiANw+\nu/dscE79gNlUIVs2n5mAt4J04X1NcOzqBpwR/j9vhzjl5C4AnBOA0Wg8fD/7igJ6jVbJUGBycC+Z\nfU1ZD8MtTNnVoxVkZMJ1qczXHXlzRIG08g2TlVAYB8gdlhfEGIetVwuAYkUFFFoHaEWF+gwvYC1p\nnx6OHxKXdXmMEIjGiLMNThrpWk/Y/zWJkTkB2aEMAIdgjmKUQpqkLsF/IP/F2AkWMCW+dGYPkgBj\nkK2YVQRsPOcn5eVsceaYEmE0KaJZGjvDD2+vTpV4p8OfhkO5ujIOeDcbQtHyWjSY6oJFgpmyDhul\naEvCKPkmCUfOQ5I6wMExDzdz5P7MdMUkkrNbSVmAMCI+/zGOVxkVMmv9eEGEg98AW7IliqlrmtNt\n/xW/p2b0KwPp349MVoEGKFrv51MjV0QLEQlSvKLMOqSERkc7OS8LgDbiWuyWNBXZCYJpsPgI50SK\nnreF4PjByTucf/ziDLndDYXZ8zXDzBj4suU04k7z6d5ofjnZptM12MdcpBLGKkWEgN/Q5kCI4d3d\n+fPhqGcrCoZsxkso5RjrltDSilk1dXRXzyn9mBL1PVOHZTL9g77DQo+bj7CVkOM6vzjPtkPpX4MF\nieAyYPc+JARr69uHblqClnq/TCcRjpFfL0Ig5NMyvGXY/XuxpopJhhHGw0ld3jfuf4ZRhq5lV98w\ng23WyLlGJ9wdmllsWbpLtppcS6WQgAmTZPMpjZRfFR3CZEydFbcueo1kucwZld8c6DYmX6Gpw/zF\n4tWewrh53uaRCKGV+6KsjIDtePMklXhj3RJ6gD639bxLhhxl1SdFitI8pLxSkDqi2PKdlAKYFuBi\np8nsH02GET3mIN+v2U7JMjwC2NbI/QPEyTe3bJ4HhbryQKahG1N8PjLdZS/ad/Sw8uoxuTVB07kK\nrEH7xdGeaknEEms8jwHLoWjSGGs8rOl+mVGaxMPyJsSycEAWSRaFIEhiyswhH+5wFLRGQUYR+Aof\nodzU3f43zLKxb16YBBlH4/nsawn8cvM23AnuMYwkit7GNPmMETPJfmW9WqvYyJBNyzx/1nGIHw79\nw6F/OPSf7NAyTaoUD9rLeAXEMANq7/B5t64lKjdKNYWdDRTsosw284Lu4aMuWOQDtokap7nKFIgd\nOhqEha1I7WNDBfL75tTVrPrAKLFHiUfZlyKCjmRDBwGUeF9xVUyvrqolQxbLKXM1E33SEbIAEYoe\n7UNm346S3CS7KMXZZZIRBJJHlO6Y7DTkR0l6qnv2nTc4oiglyqKaG9TODacnDco+tdBGrDTFNArE\nXAE/NB+z+aWAET/iEIUgYl1afdU7tTGoBoDfnImb9mA6OrkiPI0cGIf8mqHORtLQrCXzb+/zAPQI\nI75WNp4KPpgAVkcHC8d33kBms7KXc7HyjHNVRVScQhgO7fOjVDLS3SbkxzRTiNyk8n41Vg5kCO7B\n1QrFIQcuysV627XMVlk5lzKZhtJQwDS8zFJYHJi9w7HuGL+Da32tF824XVqtg1zwMx9bjsyQirEP\nrpq3A5iSq+rVkL+rsHDdUVgbwFJtTwXpkmdJt1dOJa71IshWrbcowuo2bSf+5q6gU2ggdHFwHNqf\nf29Rcn/Nn0b43tnZX27/iUN/CMPTLMaUDO/PCLfcJD4L8ePt5N789/z+bLUMgtNlFlEsTZz3q05y\nymIcP+7vV3MKKXbb8kNyt84gqhDdygqJ9TSLijpVtS0GJJYuBabhjWq1qAD2MbdJ/KuYR8v3zZmP\n8gSukvDrtMyMEnafjhZ2b23UKDEeIcm3Y4XpjvZYrfJ7paLO2X09Tofc3gZ8el66U3PdLLVjQl+3\ntxyWzktOM5mvbqX6rpHQX8EZirSLiEbJM4ylnwjMtZ+LxR9U73sSxsYiSppNI85pSOFcswrJzn3x\n7/bZfd41UV3n9+VyQ/SrbPfBWft+fxpFfZELcxJfMp5fVAxcnwe2eGjI5/reeEbaGqQZu8lZNoAi\nP2E5tXYN/jzlACnM0ywL5xETPItQC/6mijAh2DJutizj5MKprOOL8sCyyGT7WbzX6rYtooTIVq0B\nDo8DhvE3DQScdYsdNBbBWsP6aCIWqnjXpxwwWseLik92d8gu3tjRFY/ih52csLsHbjGAaZi/rVFr\nAe3jftmdu/pyN0fu5MVdXbij/5ZOq3KXHYvL/NUa3qhNjSVZOSMelE5d7JBQSmIOWrOaPbTJou1i\nb7MDD/bPz3rtiPe3LbEFaKcK20LoVmALqD8xc28ekVQ5mCfb7cCm8aY+V9YHiIarWF358a3ZWX9y\na7FZLqTmoF/Y6v8HwUXfVk2YZCzKgw45aLcU1DRvayatSla5gJ0r1lqYDgWrhfcE69Udauu8q9dU\nqw1tri7l7Zjxdkq2ehVnluD6RUl+rd1Xtmr9VhHuPEN+YYi7JS1qswvu1GjLIqTjitjvVPI77Y+S\nOXfHo2QToutRMsd6ek6/TVWdC7n2O6ZEUlvmjj0TGu5m95V3zYr7yf1wZm2ctiPOao5j//cBq26b\nbO8mp2rNjnC0W4fT6WjXBHx6XrNTc93PQP7vN8v60yHbjW/k00flwLqlXVe3a/fMnLi6azZPVBRW\nnYvpe61rLcXfrdwqgXSsuBRaN58aqFKCU33Xraleg60XovCx+ud7tk2We8vP+HbaaIX5O9tqebx2\nhZPWU/faaQtSl/KpBPkEt4Xd+juC2XZ56le2nkbVj+KtL4AC8XEn0N40E0/pi5PawyW1vhKVD/tN\ndy2NEzK16BcG9aeRW89yd40tl0kNWz5J3WrrZa7iM0nzmYKFte0TowpU8YVRjUeo+cMHilKhErHJ\n9xp4gRa0EGzHOx3aI9SXsoK51xsOhz3Mv8LmH6gCwN+h6wOw5Iygz1ai/jP2j4jQm4x5If8OOURp\n74Twll/ud0fejF+5/dcXd6tsdnrNkaYZTZZiug84htHdNLxB6SNKwRc0u3u/QjG4/vgSFFR3lwhG\nRP4FfAggxvDomvIXRsTQ3oN4ZczFcRBl/I1Cnrn4w+s3/+bqZ+uVRdTxHUmbZrGbZJQpwD+GYHeU\nyeStlxGTprdNZddChC8pG5+py2wdRTmGDN43DgvknInLjS2l/vBogyzoMhqOo2R+HEwGJCFH0hr/\nC1BLAQIUAxQAAAAIAGJU9Uhr90YTkgoAAF5CAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAACkgQAAAAAxUEsFBgAAAAAB\nAAEALwAAALEKAAAAAA==\n"}
16:56:00.943    DEBUG   Finished Request

16:56:00.944    DEBUG   POST http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub/session/e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e/element/26/value {"sessionId": "e8d83ee3-7a75-40cd-a079-bb2c83d6fb2e", "id": "26", "value": ["/", "t", "m", "p", "/", "e", "8", "d", "8", "3", "e", "e", "3", "-", "7", "a", "7", "5", "-", "4", "0", "c", "d", "-", "a", "0", "7", "9", "-", "b", "b", "2", "c", "8", "3", "d", "6", "f", "b", "2", "e", "/", "u", "p", "l", "o", "a", "d", "6", "0", "5", "4", "3", "8", "4", "5", "8", "0", "2", "8", "1", "8", "0", "7", "9", "3", "f", "i", "l", "e", "/", "1"]}"

Comment: Your question is a bit  unclear. Are you saying you have a variable like `${data}` that is set to the value `1`, and when you use it to insert into a field with `input text  <locator>  ${data}` it is inserting `/tmp/21fe989d-...`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BryanOakley yes thats correct. But this happens only when I run testcases on selenium grid

set test variable    ${data}    1
input text     <locator>     ${data}